# Jenkins in Docker Container - installing Plugins manually doesn't work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to install Jenkins plugins with jenkins-plugin-manager, it appears to work, because the plugins are in the $JENKINS_HOME/plugins folder (*.jpi), but I don't see any plugins installed in the Jenkins UI. I've tried to restart Jenkins throght UI, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently restart throught UI somehow doesn't work here. I've restartet jenkins docker container (or docker service) and now I see the installed plugins in the UI.